# How do I re-center an electron window after dynamically resizing?

Tags: javascript, electron

After calling

```
remote.getCurrentWindow().setSize(width, height);
```

the window resizes, but is not positioned in the center of the screen.  Is there a way to adjust the offset of the window relative to the screen?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

There is a `.center()` method on [`BrowserWindow`](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/browser-window#wincenter), so

```
const win = remote.getCurrentWindow();
win.setSize(width, height);
win.center();
```

centers the window after resizing.

Comment: The window jumps slightly to the top with `win.center()` Maybe +100 px or so.